# how to load ResponseCompressionDefaults function (Blazor WebAssembly SignalR)

Tags: c#, signalr, blazor, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am learning Blazor from below Microsoft's tutorial.

(https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor-webassembly?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio-mac#prerequisites)

When I write  part,
I want to use "ResponseCompressionDefaults" function, but there is red line below at my editor like screenshot.

how can I load "ResponseCompressionDefaults" function on my editor?

Please, help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQccQ.png)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSignalR();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
    {
        opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
            new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need a using statement for this to work:

`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;`